# Quick-Change of Language Environment

Tags: language-support, preferences, input-language

I'm learning French, and one thing I would like to do is to quickly switch the *entire* interface between English and French without logging in/out. Same idea as changing the keyboard layout, except changing the Interface *and* browser language preferences.

TL;DR Quick change between interface languages?

Answer (score 2):

You can select a different locale for an application from the command line by setting a couple of environment variables. First, make sure you have the appropriate language packs installed. If you can change your language (even if it requires restarting) it means you probably do. Then, on a terminal, do this (all on the same line):

```
LANG=fr_FR.UTF-8 LANGUAGE=fr_FR:fr firefox
```

This should start firefox with the french locale and everything within the app should display in french.

I know this is clunky to use and doesn't switch the entire UI over; you have to do it in an app-by-app basis. Hopefully it'll be helpful anyway.